# uk wall socket switching off and back on again

Tags: electrical

I've got an extension lead coming off of a socket that powers a washing machine and a dryer. Sometimes, possibly when they're both on at the same time, the power to the extension goes off. What's weird is that a few minutes later the power comes back again, so nothing's tripped. This socket lives on a spur that comes directly off of the main fuse board. Everything is fine when plugged into a different socket.

Any ideas what's up? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your cord have a self-healing over-current protection, your washing machine and dryer may exceed the maximum load your cord may hold so the protection kicks in, then it cools off re-establishing the connection and so on.

Another issue may be a loose contact in your outlet or in your fuse-box.

Comment: I swapped the socket faceplate, which I think had failed, and it appears ok again. Thanks